# Removing an element with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of years:

1953 - 1981

### 1962 -

Each has this HTML:

```
<span class="first">1945</span> <span>-</span> <span class="second">1954</span>
```

Some items have both years, some only the first and some items have no years. I want to remove the dash if both years are empty.  Here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if($('.first').val().length == 0 && $('.second').val().length == 0){
    $(".dash").hide();
  }
});
```

While I get no errors in the console, the code doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the dash, it should be <span class="dash">-</span>

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `text()` not `val()` which is used for form controls not content elements.

Also you need to loop over each instance and evaluate individually

Here's an example using `next()` and `prev()`

```js
$('.dash').each(function() {
  const $el = $(this)
  if (!$el.prev().text() && !$el.next().text()) {
    $el.hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="first">1945</span> <span class="dash">-</span> <span class="second">1954</span>
</div>
<div>None
  <span class="first"></span> <span class="dash">-</span> <span class="second"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="first">1945</span> <span class="dash">-</span> <span class="second"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="first">1962</span> <span class="dash">-</span> <span class="second">1980</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Using your example, I need 1945, by itself, to have a dash, like 1945 -.

Comment: @user42760 See updated answer using AND operator instead of OR. I misread requirement